# How to Connect on a different database in Try-Catch in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, connection, try-catch

I'll try my best to make this as clear as possible since I'm new to Java. If there are parts which are unclear to you, please let me know. I apologize beforehand if the structure of my coding is messy.

I'm making a `combobox` event wherein if an item is selected (or changed), it will display items of that database and if the `Update` button is clicked, the program will connect to the database based on the item selected in the combobox.

The problem is that the variable `cn` after the if-else statement, has an error of `"variable may have not been initialized"`.

Please note that I would like to focus on the condition since it is where I'm having difficulties and that the `Update` part is not a concern at this time.

```
   private void btn_UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {   
   String value2 = (String) combobox_location.getSelectedItem();
   String value4 = (String) combobox_category.getSelectedItem();
   try 
   {
    if(value2.equals(value4))
    {
    Connection cn = db.itemconnector.getConnection();
    }
    String sql = "UPDATE items set location = '"+value2+"'  where id = '"+value4+"' " ; //Please ignore this line for the now
    PreparedStatement ps1 = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps1.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update Successful");

    PreparedStatement ps2 = cn.prepareStatement(ref);
    ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)itemTable.getModel();
    tm.setRowCount(0);


    while(rs.next())
        {
            Object o[] = {rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("location"), rs.getString("product_name"),rs.getString("product_category"),rs.getString("product_description"),rs.getInt("product_stock"), rs.getFloat("product_price"), rs.getString("product_status")};
            tm.addRow(o);

        } 




}


catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Update Error!");
}

}
```

I have a package `db` that has `itemconnector` class for database connection and here is my code I've written in it. I hope I have provided all necessary details for your assistance. If you need more info, please let me know. Thank you.

```
   package db;

   import java.sql.*;

   public class itemconnector {

/**
 *
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cn = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/sales","root","");

    return cn;
}

public static Connection getConnection1() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cn = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/sales1","root","");

    return cn;
}

public static Connection getConnection2() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cn = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/sales2","root","");

    return cn;
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you are shadowing the `cn` variable in this code `if(value2.equals(value4))
    {
    Connection cn = db.itemconnector.getConnection();
    }`  If you do this you are declaring a new variable that exists only within the `if` statement

Comment: How do you suggest I fix this? I was planning on making three `If-Else` Statement to connect to three databases based on a specific condition.

Comment: change to `cn = db.itemconnector.getConnection();`

Comment: Should I just remove the `Connection`? Is it still inside the `If-Else` Statement?

Comment: Yes, but I suggest that you read some books on Java if you are asking such questions.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I will do that.